# Replacing multiple expressions in a single replacement using re.sub

Tags: python, regex, tweepy

I have following expression to remove stopwords, other characters, lower them and so on:

```
stopword_set = set(stopwords.words("english"))
return " ".join([i for i in re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]', "", raw_text).lower().split() if i not in stopword_set])
```

Now, i want to add something to:

```
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]', "", raw_text)
```

to remove urls and replace into a spacebar.
I tried several things like this: (but won't work)

```
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]["http\S+"]', "", raw_text)
```

How do I add an expression?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Can you show example inputs and the desired output for those inputs?

Comment: `["http\S+"]`  looks for any chararacter `" or h or t or p or \S or + `  - you may want `(http|\S|")` instead. Play around on http://regexr101.com

Comment: @glilch : I want to remove unnecesarry text from tweets. Like @, # and also urls